# how does this pandas snippet code work behind the scene

Tags: python, pandas

data = credit_data[credit_data['CREDIT_LIMIT'].isna()]

this is the code snippet from a code I was writing.
Here I wanted to print all the rows that contain nan values in a column.
This code accomplishes that but what I want to know is how is this actually happening.

As credit_data['CREDIT_LIMIT'].isna() prints out a series containing bool values so how by just passing that series through our dataframe (credit_data) we are getting all the rows that contain nan values

at this point I have searched on some blogs and pandas documentation for dataframe.isna()
and some answers on this site but haven't found anything satisfactory.
I would be great if you can point me right direction like give a blog post link or some answer that already answers this query
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As credit_data['CREDIT_LIMIT'].isna() prints out a series containing
> bool values so how by just passing that series through our dataframe
> (credit_data) we are getting all the rows that contain nan values

By passing boolean Series you have used feature named **Boolean Masking**, it is done by providing iterable (which might be, but does not have to be Series) of bool values of length equal to DataFrame, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'letter':['A','B','C','D','E']})
mask = [True,False,True,False,True]
print(df[mask])
```

output

```
  letter
0      A
2      C
4      E
```

Note that this feature is also present in `numpy` for example

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))
mask = [True,False,True,False,True]
print(arr[mask])
```

output

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```